# I am trying to emulate a board which has a OLED display, but can't see anything. Can you tell me if there is something important I am not considering?

Tags: arm, embedded, emulation, qemu, device-driver

I am just a newbie that is trying to learn. I can't see anything in the OLED display (ssd0303).
[image]

I am just using this demo: https://www.freertos.org/portlm3s811keil.html

as you can see it says that:

> The print task is the only task permitted to access the LCD - thus
> ensuring mutual exclusion and consistent access to the resource. Other
> tasks do not access the LCD directly, but instead send the text they
> wish to display to the print task. The print task spends most of its
> time blocked - only waking when a message is queued for display.

but actually, if I compile using `make` and running using `qemu-system-arm -M lm3s811evb -kernel gcc/RTOSDemo.bin` I can only see that black screen.

Why? Is there something I am not considering? It should work out of the box, since it's also writen in the official doc that I mentioned. So why I see black screen?

Probably there is something I am not considering because I am a newbie

Comment: That page doesn't say anything about QEMU -- are you sure the demo binary is known to work on it? If it tries to use some bit of the hardware QEMU doesn't emulate, it will probably crash and not display anything...

Comment: @PeterMaydell how to invastigate? can you give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by compiling via Keil instead of gcc:
https://forums.freertos.org/t/i-am-trying-to-emulate-a-board-which-has-a-oled-display-but-cant-see-anything-can-you-tell-me-if-there-is-something-important-i-am-not-considering/18689/3